# What's the animal that has the most frequent matings per day?

Tags: syntax

For a purpose of a riddle, I'm looking for a way to ask about the quantity or length in the following context and I find it a bit confusing:

What's the animal that has the most frequent matings per day?
I mean to ask what's animal that by its nature has the highest average of matings per day.
I'm struggling to say it syntax-correct, and I'm not sure what sounds natural / understood the English native speaker.

Comment: "Which animal mates the most often in a day?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think

> Which animal mates more frequently than any other?

sounds correct